# Clone a node programmatically

Tags: nodes, 8

I am modifying the node content on `hook_form_alter()` as follows.

```
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
  if ($node) {
    $node->field_p_frontip = $availableip[0];
    $node->save();
  }
```

I need to clone the node and save it in the  `hook_form_alter()` submission. How could I do this?

**UPDATE**

---

In **D6** the node was cloned using the function [clone_node_save](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!node_clone!clone.pages.inc/function/clone_node_save/6) which uses the node id to clone as **`clone_node_save($nid,false);`**, what is the corresponding function in **D8** ??

Comment: Question has been updated for clarity, but I can't add an answer to a question on hold. In Drupal 8, any entity can be cloned using `EntityInterface::createDuplicate()`. So in the case of your node object: `$cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate()`. Calling `$cloned_node->save()` will save a new node with a different ID.

Comment: Thanks @jhedstrom :) . Here **$node** is the node id right ?

Comment: Thanks man , it worked :)) . I dont know why its put on hold . CRAP

Comment: I've added this comment as a proper answer now that this is not on hold.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Drupal 8, any entity can be cloned using `EntityInterface::createDuplicate()`. So in the case of your node object: `$cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate()`. Calling `$cloned_node->save()` will save a new node with a different ID.

Comment: Hi @jhedstrom, is there any way to get the nid of recently cloned node ?

Comment: @innovativekundan indeed. After calling `$cloned_node->save()`, you would simply call `$cloned_node->id()` to get the new node ID.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!-- The below solution works for me. (Drupal - 9.4.1)
1. It perfectly clones all paragraphs.
2. It does not clone files.
3. It does not clone terms. -->

$nid = 17; // Example node id
$node = Node::load($nid);

if (is_object($node)) {
  $clonednode = $node->createDuplicate();
  // Loop over entity fields and duplicate nested paragraphs.
  foreach ($clonednode->getFields() as $field) {
    if ($field->getFieldDefinition()->getType() == 'entity_reference_revisions') {
      if ($field->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getSetting('target_type') == "paragraph") {
        $paragraphs = [];
        foreach ($field as $item) {
          $paragraphs[] = $item->entity->createDuplicate();
        }
        $fieldname = $field->getFieldDefinition()->getName();
        $clonednode->$fieldname =  $paragraphs;
      }
    }
  }

  $clonednode->changed->value = time();

  // Append cloned in the title.
  $clonednode->set('title', 'Cloned - ' . $node->getTitle());

  // Cloned node should be unpublished.
  $clonednode->set('status', 0);

  $clonednode->save();
}
```