# How to duplicate nodes programmatically?

Tags: nodes, 8, migrations

I want to create duplicate nodes of a content type programmatically.

Is there any way to do this?

*Note: I don't want to use any module to do this.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Drupal 8, any entity can be cloned using EntityInterface::createDuplicate(). So in the case of your node object: $cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate(). Calling $cloned_node->save() will save a new node with a different ID.

Answer from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219654/93452)

Answer (score 7):

You can read the values from the original node in an array and create a new node with the data:

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

$node = $storage->load($nid);

$original_values = $node->toArray();

// assign content type as string, the array causes an error when creating a new node
$original_values['type'] = $node->bundle();

// change title
$original_values['title'] = $node->label() . ' (cloned)';

// remove nid and uuid, the cloned node is assigned new ones when saved
unset($original_values['nid']);
unset($original_values['uuid']);

// remove revision data, the latest revision becomes the only one in the new node
unset($original_values['vid']);
unset($original_values['revision_translation_affected']);
unset($original_values['revision_uid']);
unset($original_values['revision_log']);
unset($original_values['revision_timestamp']);

$node_cloned = $storage->create($original_values);
$node_cloned->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can duplicate a node in Drupal 8 as well. Check example below:

***NOTE: I've not tested this code thoroughly, and not sure if this will affect on node being cloned as well.***

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node_clone = Node::load($id);
$node_clone->nid = NULL;
$node_clone->vid = NULL;
$node_clone->tnid = NULL;
$node_clone->log = NULL;
// Also handle modules that attach a UUID to the node.
$node_clone->uuid = \Drupal::service('uuid')->generate();
$node_clone->vuuid = NULL;

// Anyonmymous users don't have a name.
$node_clone->name = 'Anonymous';
$node_clone->uid = 0;

$node_clone->created = time();
$node_clone->path = NULL;
$node_clone->files = array();
$node_clone->setTitle('Clone Node');
$node_clone->save();
```

Comment: It's not working as it reflect changes on the old node only, no new node is cloned from it.

Comment: Are you getting any error while running above code?

Comment: My original node has been changed through this code. It's not working

Comment: Ok, did you also tried the solution provided by @4k4. I'll try out the above example and see what is causing this issue.